# How to construct nested eventlisteners in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, event-listener

Working a bit with AS3 and hit a wall on how to program through this situation. I have a class which represents a number say 103. I have a movieclip for each digit which I add to a holding movieclip and then add to the stage. I want to enable the ability to single click a digit like the zero in the number 103 and have it react since it is an individual movieclip and at the same time double click the entire number and have that react. Is there a way to cleanly do this wtihout confusing the code below is what I have thus far.

```
public function test()
    {
        numberimage = new MovieClip();
        var images:Vector.<MovieClip> = generateNumericArray("");
        for (var i:int = 0; i < String(value).length; i++) {
            var temp:MovieClip = parsevalue(String(value).substr(i,1),images);
            temp.x = i*50;
                            temp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click)
            numberimage.addChild(temp);
        }
        numberimage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,drag);
        numberimage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,drop);
        numberimage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,doubleClick);
        stage.addChild(numberimage);
    }
```

any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: `at the same time double click the entire number and have that react`,  Can you explain more about this?

Comment: @Tim I have a function in the class which will cause movieclips to glow. So depending on if the number is being clicked or dragged it will glow different colors. Now since I have the all the movie clips grouped for the entire number underneath another movieclip (example the number 103 would have movie clips for the 1, 0 and the 3 under a single movie clip. As of now I can only make the whole number respond to the movieclip and do not have the ability to have only a single digit respond.

Answer (score 0):

Do, doubleclick on clip : stop listening to main movie, and listen now to sub clips. On click outside the main clip, listen back to the main movie and stop listening to its children.

Comment: not sure what you mean... So you are saying in the doubleclick function call to turn off the children eventlisteners? Also how will flash be able to seperate the first click of a doubleclick on the parent vs just single clicking a child. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is 100% what you are looking for: use the following, depending on what you are adding the listener to. You do have to enable double clicking first

```
numberimage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
numberimage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, click);
```